# SQL Server deadlock between transactional INSERTs and single SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock, isolation

The deadlock occurs between `SELECT...JOIN` query that is running without any explicit transaction and a transaction with `INSERT`s in it.

`INSERT`s have the order we cannot change (insert Person, then insert Employment). It seems however the tables used in the `SELECT` clause are locked in opposite order (Employment then Person).

Unfortunately it is not so easy to change the `SELECT` (i.e. the order of tables involved) because it is generated by a complex legacy engine.

Is there any way to lock tables used in a `SELECT...JOIN` query in the order we need?

I do not want to go to a complex solution like Snapshot isolation. I do not want to use `NOLOCK` in that `SELECT` either.

Deadlock graph xml:

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process8bfdd2188" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process8bfdd2188" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 223:1:769193 " waittime="4340" ownerId="17504759932" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2016-04-02T03:03:25.527" XDES="0x63f8f1cc0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="2" kpid="27920" status="suspended" spid="954" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2016-04-02T03:03:25.523" lastbatchcompleted="2016-04-02T03:03:25.523" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.523" clientapp="Security Services" hostname="A-PRI0010IIS" hostpid="29908" loginname="SWE2078262_EOUser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="17504759932" currentdb="223" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="58" sqlhandle="0x020000000b6f1301768ce09dcc48ead49292f31b2305871b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
select distinct em.EmploymentId.. from employment.Employment as em left join employment.Person as p on ...  </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@dp1 datetime,@dp2 datetime)select em.EmploymentId from employment.Employment as em left join employment.Person as p on ...</inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process8e5957498" taskpriority="0" logused="120220" waitresource="OBJECT: 223:1938105945:0 " waittime="4207" ownerId="17504759159" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-04-02T03:03:25.333" XDES="0x254d02d08" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="1" kpid="23832" status="suspended" spid="924" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2016-04-02T03:03:25.703" lastbatchcompleted="2016-04-02T03:03:25.703" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.703" clientapp="Security Services" hostname="A-PRI0010IIS" hostpid="29908" loginname="SWE2078262_EOUser" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="17504759159" currentdb="223" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="360" sqlhandle="0x020000002d54221bf934de11467adec42e4bb5413da44e120000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
insert [employment].[Employment]([EmploymentId], [CompanyId], [PersonId], ...</frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 uniqueidentifier,@2 uniqueidentifier,@3 varchar(30),@4 datetime2(7),@5 datetime2(7),@6 nvarchar(50),@7 decimal(18,2),@8 nvarchar(50),@9 bit,@10 varchar(15))insert [employment].[Employment]([EmploymentId], [CompanyId], [PersonId]...
   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="769193" dbid="223" subresource="FULL" objectname="SWE2078262_Core.employment.Person" id="lock1f1566080" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594248167424">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process8e5957498" mode="IX" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process8bfdd2188" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1938105945" subresource="FULL" dbid="223" objectname="SWE2078262_Core.employment.Employment" id="lock2341db7480" mode="S" associatedObjectId="1938105945">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process8bfdd2188" mode="S" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process8e5957498" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </objectlock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: "i.e. the order of tables involved" - which is generally irrelevant anyway, unless `OPTION FORCE ORDER` has been applied to the `SELECT`. It's the job of the optimizer to determine what order tables are accessed in and there's no guarantee it matches the original textual order from the query. At a bit of a loss with how to help you here though, since you don't seem to want to change *any* of the code.

Comment: You should handle deadlock exceptions then, on both sides.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, actually I can change the code for `SELECT` but I did not want to do changes in logic of that code generator. So, to add i.e. `FORCE ORDER` is possible but the order itself is defined by code logic and I do not want to change that logic.

Answer (score 0):

You still probably want to use one of these:

1. Optimistic concurrency, i.e. Snapshot isolation mode for your db and the select query.
2. Repeat deadlocked transaction. I mean you need to catch the SqlException in your C# code (I assume you use C#) and repeat the query (it can be insert or select).